# Doubt on Universal Property from morphisim preserving groups.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Theorem:Let, $\mathbb{N}$ be the set of natural numbers $0$ included, $\mathbb{Z}$ set of integers (which is a group under $+$) and also let $(G,\oplus)$ be a group set $f:\mathbb{N}\longrightarrow G$ be a map such that $f(m+n)=f(m)\oplus f(n)$
Let $\phi:\mathbb{N}\longrightarrow\mathbb{Z}$ be a natural map. Then there exist a morphisim (homomorphisim) $\psi:\mathbb{Z}\longrightarrow G$ such that $\psi \circ \phi=f$.

My attempt of proof:

We know natural map $\mathbb{N}\longrightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ is  $\phi(2k)=k$ and $\phi(2k-1)=-k$ and $\phi(0)=0$

Taking $\psi(0)=f(0)$ , $\psi(k)=\bigoplus_{i=1}^{2k} f(1)$ and $\psi(-k)=\bigoplus_{i=1}^{2k-1} f(1)$

The map $\psi$ is clearly well defined.

Since $\psi$ is a group homomorphisim we must have $\psi(0)=\psi(k)\oplus\psi(-k)=\bigoplus_{i=1}^{4k-1} f(1)=f(0)$
Hence $\psi(k)$ and $\psi(-k)$ are inverses of eachother. Thus, easy to obesrve $\psi \circ \phi=f$
$\blacksquare$

$*$ Remark: Now clearly $S=\{ \psi(k)| k\in\mathbb{Z} \}$ is a subgroup of $G$ where homomorphisim of $\psi$ preserves.

I want to know, was my proof correct or there is any flaw.
What if I am given a general 1-1 map $\phi$ from $\mathbb{N}\longrightarrow\mathbb{Z}$.

Also I wanted to know a natural map means a general map from ,$\phi$ or the map I defined is the natural map.

Any answer or comments will be helpful.

Comment: No, the "natural map" $\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{Z}$ is the **embedding** map, sending $n\in\mathbb{N}$ to itself, but viewed as an element of $\mathbb{Z}$. You want $\phi$ to be an additive map, and your "natural map" is not additive: $\phi(1+1)=\phi(2)$ maps to $1$, but $\phi(1)=-1$ so $\phi(1)+\phi(1)=-2$.

Comment: Don't know who called it a "natural map"; that's not standard terminology.

Comment: Actually, I didn't take notes in the class and my some of friend said natural map. Thank You Sir!!!.Now if I erase Natural map and replace by the word map only does we allowed to take $\phi$ as I defined or it's in general can be any map? Can you plz clarify this point.

Comment: No, you can't take $\phi$ as you defined. As I said explicitly in my comment, the map being refered to is the embedding of $\mathbb{N}$ into $\mathbb{Z}$ sending $n$ to itself.  What was unclear about that statement?

Comment: Okay got it!!! $\phi$ needs  to be an additive map right? Then it would be done!!! Am I right?

Comment: No, you are still not reading what I wrote: $\phi$ needs to be the map that sends $n\in\mathbb{N}$ to itself, just as I've said twice (and now three times).

Comment: Ah!! $\phi(n)=n$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$

Comment: Thank You!!! Now I will think The problem is that I stuck in the place what actually $\phi$ is.If I know the definition , correct phrase should be "embedding" map, that send every elemnt of $\mathbb{N}$ to itself.

Comment: Sir, Can Anyone just tell me, $\psi(n)=f(n)$ and $\psi(-n)=-f(n)$ where, $\phi(n)=n$ works for the problem right? I mean $\psi$ is well defined.Where $f(n)$ and $-f(n)$ are inverses of eachother.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know who calls it a "natural map $\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{Z}$"... that's terrible terminology, and it is definitely *not* the map you have. There is nothing "natural" (or "obvious") about the map you have, though it is probably an instance of a bijection you've seen between $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{Z}$ (though hardly the only one).

Instead, the unambiguous way to state the theorem is:

> **Theorem.** let $\phi\colon\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{Z}$ be the standard embedding sending $n\in\mathbb{N}$ to $n\in\mathbb{Z}$. Let $(G,\oplus)$ be any group, and let $f\colon\mathbb{N}\to G$ be a map such that $f(n+m)=f(n)\oplus f(m)$ for all $n,m\in\mathbb{N}$(*). Then there exists a unique group homomorphism $\psi\colon\mathbb{Z}\to G$ such that $f=\psi\circ\phi$.

(*) That is, $f$ is a semigroup homomorphism from $\mathbb{N}$ to $G$.

I would note that using $\oplus$ is very bad form, since $G$ is not assumed to be commutative; and using $0$ for the identity of $G$ is also likewise very bad form.

Before establishing the result, let's take a closer look at your attempt.

---

You assert that your $\psi$ is a group homomorphism. The only time $\psi$ is a group homomorphism is if $f(n)=e_G$ (the identity of $G$) for all $n$.

Indeed, suppose that $\psi$ is a group homomorphism. By definition, we have
$$\begin{align*}
\psi(1) &= \oplus_{i=1}^2f(1)= f(1)+f(1)=f(2),\\
\psi(-1) &= \oplus_{i=1}^{1}f(1) = f(1).
\end{align*}$$
If $\psi$ is a group homomorphism, then $\psi(1)$ must be the inverse of $\psi(-1)$, so $e_G = \psi(1)\ominus\psi(-1)$. But that means that $f(1)+f(1)\ominus f(1) = e_G$, so $f(1)$ must be the identity of $G$. And since $f$ is additive, it follows that $f(n)=e_G$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

(Conversely, if $f(n)=e_G$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, then your $\psi$ is $e_G$ for all $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ and everything works out; but this is the *only* situation where what you've written actually gives a group homomorphism.)

You simply tells us that "$\oplus_{i=1}^{4k-1}f(1)= 0$". There is really absolutely no justification for this assertion, and as noted above, that assertion simply does not follow from what you have. What you get is $(4k-1)f(1)$, which is zero if and only if $f(1)$ happens to have order dividing $4k-1$, which is hardly a given.

"Thus it is easy to observe that $\psi\circ\phi = f$... that is not a conclusion ("thus"...) and it is not that easy to observe, though it is true given your definition for $\phi$.  But anyway, what you have is not true, since your $\psi$ will generally not be a homomorphism.

---

As to the proof: with any "there exists a unique" argument, it is usually easier to first prove that there exists such an object, then prove it is unique.

**Existence.** It is clear that we need $\psi(0)=e_G$ and $\psi(k)=f(k)$ for all $k\gt 0$. That means that we must define $\psi(-k) = \ominus f(k)$, the inverse of $f(k)$ under $\oplus$.

Note that for all integers $m$, positive or negative, we have $\psi(-m)=\ominus \psi(k)$: if $k$ is positive, then this is because $\psi(-k)=\ominus f(k) = \ominus \psi(k)$. If $k$ is negative, then $-k$ is positive, so $\psi(-k) = f(k) = \ominus(\ominus f(k)) = \ominus \psi(k)$.

We need to check that this is a group homomorphism. Let $m,n\in\mathbb{Z}$.

1. If either (or both) $m$ and $n$ are zero, then $\psi(m+n)=\psi(m)\oplus\psi(n)$.
2. If both $m$ and $n$ are positive then $\psi(m+n)=f(m+n) = f(m)\oplus f(n) = \psi(m)\oplus \psi(n)$ and
   $$\psi((-m)+(-n)) = \psi(-(m+n)) = \ominus \psi(m+n) = \ominus (\psi(m)\oplus \psi(n)) = (\ominus\psi(m))\oplus(\ominus\psi(n)) = \psi(-m)\oplus\psi(-n).$$
   This coverse the "both positive" and "both negative" cases.
3. If one of $m$ and $n$ is positive and the other negative, assume first that $m\gt 0\gt n$. Then
   $$\begin{align*}
   \psi(m) &= \psi( (m+n)+ (-n))\\
    &= \psi(m+n)\oplus \psi(-n) &\text{(by the case where both are positive)}\\
   &= \psi(m+n)\ominus \psi(n).
   \end{align*}$$
   Moving $\psi(n)$ to the left hand side, we have
   $$\psi(m)\oplus \psi(n) = \psi(m+n).$$
   If $n\gt 0 \gt m$, then reverse the roles of $m$ and $n$.

This proves that $\psi$ is a group homomorphism.

**Uniqueness**. A group homomorphism $\theta\colon\mathbb{Z}\to G$ is completely determined by the value $\theta(1)$ (meaning, two homomorphisms that take the same value at $1$ are equal). If $\theta$ also satisfies $\theta\circ\phi=f$, then $\theta(1) = \theta(\phi(1)) = f(1) = \psi(\phi(1)) = \psi(1)$, so $\theta=\psi$. This proves uniqueness.

Comment: Thank you! Sir it is helpful

Comment: Exactly, I commented in the question feed this construction before your comment and suprisingly my comment works!!!! after it got clear to me what \phi is. Many Many Thanks and Indeed the proof is similar to Universal property of modules and Rings expect for the construction part. Anyways Many Many Thanks Again!!